# Question about Django tutorial official part3 html code

Tags: python, django

I have a question about the js code when I'am learning on Django official tutorial part3. In the "Raising a 404 error" section, the official code use following code to display the "question_text" in object called "question":

```
{{ question }}
```

I don't understand why this code could work. The "question" is not a string but a object. It should be "question.question_text" .

**`views.py`**

```
def detail(request, question_id):
    try:
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Question does not exist")
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

**`models.py`**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('datepublished')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Besides, It works when I use the code `{{ question.question_text }}`
So, I want to know why those two can have same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you defined a `__str__` for the object:

```
class Question(models.Model):

    # ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

Django implicitly calls `str(..)` over the variables. In case you did not override the `__str__` it would still render something: the `__str__` of the superclass. The same happens for non-model objects (like `int`s, lists, tuples, custom class objects, etc.).

Since models by default have a `__str__` that looks approximately like `Model object (id)`, if you do not override the `__str__` (nor some superclass in between), then it will thus render the object that way. So if you would not provide a `__str__` yourself, it would look like `Question object (123)` (with `123` the `id` of the object).

Note that you by writing `{{ question }}` thus depend on the `__str__` function: if you later change the `__str__`, the rendering will change. So in case you need the `question_text`, it is better to do this *explicitly*.